# sum all values for table column based on class and show in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a tutorial i followed for reference: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/07/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript.html

Here is my javascript....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
                //handler to trigger sum event
                $(".txt").each(function() {

                  $("#btn").click(function(){
                    calculateSum();
                    $("#sum").show();
                    });
                });

            });

            function calculateSum() {

               var sum = 0;
                //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
                $(".txt").each(function() {

                    //add only if the value is number
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }

                });
                //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
                $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
</script>
```

This is my html code to show the sum value..

```
    <table width="1177" border="1" cellspacing="5" id="add" class="add">
      <tr>
        <td width="71" height="42"><button class="add">Add Rows</button></td>

        <td width="144"><div align="center"><strong>Product Name</strong></div></td>
        <td width="146"><div align="center"><strong>Brand Name</strong></div></td>
        <td width="146"><div align="center"><strong>Model No</strong></div></td>
        <td width="146"><div align="center"><strong>Dealer Price</strong> (DP)</div></td>
        <td width="146"><div align="center"><strong>Quantity (Q)</strong></div></td>
        <td width="146"><div align="center"> <strong>Total Price</strong> (TP)        </div>
          <div align="center">
            (TP = DP x Q)
</div>
        </td>
        <td width="153"><div align="center"><strong>Quality</strong></div></td> 
         <td><div align="center"><strong>Insert Image</strong></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="prototype">
          <td height="26"><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="model[]" id="model" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="dprice[]" class="price"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity"/></td>
          <td><input name="txt[]" type="text" class="txt" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quality[]" id="quality"/></td>
           <td><input name="images[]" type="file"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="26"><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="model[]" id="model" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="dprice[]" class="price"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity"/></td>
          <td><input name="txt[]" type="text" class="txt" id="tp" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quality[]" id="quality"/></td>
           <td><input name="images[]" type="file" id="image"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="26"><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="model[]" id="model" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="dprice[]" class="price"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity"/></td>
          <td><input name="txt[]" type="text" class="txt" id="tp" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quality[]" id="quality"/></td>
           <td><input name="images[]" type="file" id="image"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="26"><button class="remove">Remove</button></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="product[]" id="product" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="brand[]" id="brand" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="model[]" id="model" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="dprice[]" class="price"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity"/></td>
          <td><input name="txt[]" type="text" class="txt" id="tp" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quality[]" id="quality"/></td>
           <td><input name="images[]" type="file" id="image"/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

<table width="1206" border="0">

  <tr>
    <td width="905">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="86"><input name="btn" type="submit" id="btn" value="Grand Total" /></td>

    <td width="201"><input name="sum" type="text" id="sum"/></td>
</tr>
```

How to show this sum value in textbox after button click.

Please help...

Comment: where is your textbox

Comment: full html markup please, what is `.txt`? Why do you need to iterate over `.txt` elements to add a click handler to `#btn`?

Comment: ID of an element must be unique.. so every row cannot have an element with id `sum` or `btn`

Comment: have you tried any answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with val() method I have edited the answer..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".txt").each(function () {

        $("#btn").click(function () {
            calculateSum();
            $("#sum").show();
           });
      });

   });

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function () {

        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length> 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

</script>
```

here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDcMP/)

Comment: to set value to textbox we can use .val() method in jquery

Comment: but where is textbox here? `<td width="201"><span id="sum"></span></td>`

Comment: "How to show this sum value in textbox after button click." this is what he asked in the question... and "if "sum" is the Id for your text box then" this is how I gave the answer

Comment: I am sure, OP is confusing and don't know the meaning of TEXTBOX here, i think he/she is calling a table's cell as a textbox. Its just a sense according to his/her html

Comment: Yes may be..  I posted the answer before he updated his code with the HTML part..

Comment: how to use this without button click @Myth

Comment: u can use  $(".txt").change(function () {
            calculateSum();
            $("#sum").show();
           });   @AM26   check the fiddle i posted.. now http://jsfiddle.net/PDcMP/1/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I know this is the kind of answer that annoys people but...
Have you tried debuging javascript? It is possible to debug javascript code. For example using firebug: https://getfirebug.com/javascript . It might help.

Also, where are you assigning value of Sum to anything? Are you sure you did not want sum to be global variable (outside of any function)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#idOfTextBox').val(sum.toFixed(2));
```